# noticable lag reading text off a google doc by google app script and rendering on page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

have built a personal website using Google App Script - shows my cv, work samples etc

There is a css accordion menu with links to cv etc and a main div (main stage area) to feature the linked content.

At the moment the only workable method of fetching text data (like my cv or bio) that I managed to get working is by having google text docs with required text and using getText() method in code.js to load the text into a variable which is than rendered inside the main div using innerHtml

This is the function fetching the text data

```
function getDocContent(docID) {
  var docx = DocumentApp.openById(docID);
  var body = docx.getText();
  return body;
}
```

Anyway the main issue seems to be latency from clicking the link to the point it is rendered. I am not sure if it is solvable or if there are more efficient methods of storing text data into variables and fetching it (other than adding these vars to the JavaScript page which will make it very large and messy to maintain)

I was trying to create separate js page (data.js) which only defines the variables holding the text data but cant make it work (main js page does not seem to see the vars on the data.js page)

Comment: How long does it take and how much text is it?

Comment: i would say about a second or two - regardless of how much text (one page has some 50 lines the other maybe 8) -  I have made published it now so I can demostrate the delay - its www.michelmoalem.com select "film and video " from the sliding menu, and click on either of the first two links showing underneath in the sub menu

Comment: You could load the text into another div as the page loads and then display it directly from that page when you click a button.

Comment: I thought i found another solution - I am using google sites as host to the webapp. I created a second html page there that can containg the cv than hid it from the navigation menu so its only visiable if you know the full address. So i thought I could include it in an iframe but alas it doesnt work - I get this notification "www.michelmoalem.com refused to connect."

Comment: yes, i guess pre-loading will work. thanks for the idea. and in regard to the slowness - I am not sure why - it really is very simple site- css driven animated menu, one small image loaded from google drive (my name as showing when menu collapsed) couple of links to text from google doc (will bee few more when finished but for now thats it )

Comment: holding cv in text document allows me simple editing and updating rather than changing the code in the webapp just to add a line to the cv.

Comment: i could write it in google sites and edit it there as it functions as a basic word processor but I dont know why I cant embed it as iframe

Comment: Actually after looking at it again I like the look and the text loads pretty fast actually I was expecting a little more on the first page so I thought it was loading slowly but you probably haven't completed the page yet.

Comment: thanks - yes it is a work in progress - alough I rather people explore through simple short menus and be curious whats more is hidden in the page... not really a web designer so just guessing...